# (Yet Another) 'ImportError: No module named my_module'

Tags: python

Ok, I stripped the code to ultra minimal to illustrate the problem and make it reproducible

context :

- Python 3.7
- No VENV or funny stuff

Talk is cheap. Show you the code :

code structure :

```
$ tree pymod/
pymod/
├── modone
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── one.py
└── modtwo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── two.py
```

**init.py** is everywhere where it should be, obviously

one.py :

```
from modtwo import two
class One():
    @staticmethod
    def print_one():
        print("this is one")
        two.print_two()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    One().print_one()
```

two.py :

```
class Two():
    @staticmethod
    def print_two():
        print("this is from two")
```

error thrown

```
$ python modone/one.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modone/one.py", line 1, in <module>
    from modtwo import two
  ImportError: No module named modtwo
```

What I tried so far :

- Appended every possible directory to PYTHONPATH
- ran the command from project root and relative paths
- scratched my head compulsively

**EDIT AFTER ANSWERS :**

What I've learned so far :

- modules and scripts are two different concepts.
  they are like the light wave/particle duality 
  they should hence be called/treated as such (either as a module, or a script)
- a module can be run as a script, but it won't be aware of the directory structures around it

Comment: One general advise is to follow naming conventions in python, especially making class name starting with a capital letter. This might reduce confusion when your module has the same name as your class. Be aware that a python module is not the same as a python class. One module can have multiple classes

Comment: Have you installed [pymod](https://pypi.org/project/pymod/)? If so then there is a name clash

Comment: @YannickFunk yes I am well aware of all these aspect, thank you for reminding. Actually I just have spit a quick and dirty example to illustrate and tackle the issue. Updated

Comment: @roganjosh that would not have thrown such and error imho. But yeah could result in some trouble if it were the case

Comment: I'm not so sure it _wouldn't_ have caused that error due to [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). In any case, I find the import/packaging system difficult plenty of times, so I'm not gonna waste your time by throwing out suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're calling the print_two method.
You called two, which is a module, that's why you got "module is not callable"

```
from modtwo import two
class One():
    @staticmethod
    def print_one():
        print("this is one")
        two().print_two()
```

You should access the class first

```
from modtwo import two
class One():
    @staticmethod
    def print_one():
        print("this is one")
        two.Two.print_two()
```

And run the script like this

```
python -m modone.one
```

The result is:

```
this is one
this is from two
```

Comment: Coming from java background, Filenames and Classnames are (often) the same. 
This can lead to confusion in Python indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a package-like directory structure, run python with the `-m` option to run a module as a script:

```
python -m modone.one
```

Also there is a bug in your one.py. You call `print_two` on the module you imported, not on the class inside the module.

Comment: I did try this option indeed, forgot to mention it. 
Throws `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
regarding the "bug" I updated it (just a typo while typing the case)

Comment: Also, why can't a module be called as a script ? 
In the configuration in Pycharm for example, I can run whatever py file right off the bat, module or not

Comment: `two.two.print_two()` it should be in your example. That should fix the new type error you get. Of course you can run any python file normally, but it won't be aware of the directory structures around it. @MehdiLAMRANI

Comment: that last comment definitely brings light to my questioning. Thanks !

Comment: Does that mean that if called as a scripts, imports outside of the package would not be reconized ? How does IDE's like pacharm manage that ?